# Instanceof works if project is run from eclipse, but not when its exported

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a project that has to dynamically load `.jar` files from a folder. It gets all files from the folder that end with `.jar` and then opens them. It then gets every file inside the jar file ending with `.class` and loads it. I am then checking if the class extends `LeafPlugin`with the following code:

```java
Class<?> clazz = classloader.loadClass(classname);
Object object = clazz.newInstance();
if(object instanceof LeafPlugin){
     // Load LeafPlugin
}else{
     System.out.println("Class '" + classname + "' isn't a LeafPlugin");
}
```

While this works fine with the exported DemoPlugin inside eclipse, if the project is exported, the message that the class isn't a LeafPlugin gets printed out. What is causing this wierd behaviour?

I have this project in the build path of the plugin, so the LeafPlugin shouldn't be different.

I have tried using `LeafPlugin.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)`, but it didn't change anything. What could be different from running it inside eclipse to running it if it exported?

The whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/NoRelect/Leaf) (It is quite a lot, so just take a look at the [LeafPluginLoader](https://github.com/NoRelect/Leaf/blob/master/core/src/ch/norelect/leaf/plugin/LeafPluginLoader.java))

Comment: You might try setting the parent class loader for the  classloader you load your plugins with to your current classloader *getClass().getClassLoader()*

Comment: @ug_  you can post it as the answer, it worked! (Code: `ClassLoader parent = LeafPluginLoader.class.getClassLoader();` and `URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls,parent);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you defined your ClassLoader in your `LeafPluginLoader`. You did not provide the code for it in your question (its on your GitHub tho). You have it as

```
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
```

The issue is this class loader knows nothing of your current `LeafPlugin` class. You need to pass the `ClassLoader` instance which also loaded the `LeafPlugin` class.

`URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, LeafPlugin.class.getClassLoader());`

---

Now I dont know classloader behavior enough to really explain in detail why this is the case, however simply put you must do this because ClassLoaders have a scope of classes it knows about. When loading in your plugins if the Classloader which loaded them doesnt know about the `LeafPlugin` class then your going to have issues.